# How to redirect input to program and kill the application if it takes too long

Tags: batch-file, redirect, stdout, stdin, kill

I have the following code to call an application with input and output redirection

```
%prgm1% < %testDir%\!filename! > %prgm1OutputDir%\!filename!
```

The problem comes in when the target application for some reason does not end and the batch script waits for ever. I need to redirect input and output while also adding a timeout to the application. I tried:

```
start %prgm1% < %testDir%\!filename! > %prgm1OutputDir%\!filename!
timeout /t 2
taskkill /im %prgm1% /f
```

but it ends up opening a large amount of tabs on my console and not redirecting input and output.

How can I implement killing the application if it takes longer than lets say 2 seconds if it does not end itself while also redirecting input and output without additional consoles tabs opening?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your command is redirecting the `stdin` and `stdout` streams of the `start` command, instead of redirecting the streams of your program.

Not knowing the exact content of the variables make it impossible to determine where to properly quote commands, but you could try with something like

```dos
start /b "" cmd /c "%prgm1% < %testDir%\!filename! > %prgm1OutputDir%\!filename! "
timeout /t 2
taskkill /im %prgm1% /f
```

That is, start a new cmd instance that will run the command while handling the redirection

Another option is to do just the oposite: execute in a separate instance the process killing code and leave to the current `cmd` instance handle the redirection

```dos
start /b "" cmd /c ">nul timeout /t 2 & taskkill /im %prgm1% /f" 
%prgm1% < %testDir%\!filename! > %prgm1OutputDir%\!filename!
```